# PHP-FPM does not use memory

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm

I run PHP7.1.15-FPM with nginx on an EC2 Instance. I installed Magento 2 which requires a lot of resources (e.g. 2Gb Memory). When I look at the default configuration of nginx, php-fpm and Magento, everything is setup with a memory_limit of `756M`. I updated the PHP-FPM ini under `/etc/php/7.1/fpm/php.ini` and updated the `memory_limit` from the default value to 2268M. 
I restarted the service with `service php7.1-fpm restart`, reloaded the site and the new value does not appear. I also restarted the nginx (just to make sure...). When I look closer to the `phpinfo()` output, there are a lot of other configuration files that are parsed and in addition to that, there is an Env Var that also sets the `memory_limit`. I wonder which file, var, whatever overwrites another?

Besides that, even the phpinfo() site takes seconds to load. The Server itself has "enough" resources (2CPU's, 4Gb Memory).

Comment: Find the ini file that phpinfo() says is in use, change that one.

Comment: Yes, I did. /etc/php/7.1/fpm/php.ini. Didn't work